# How to map List<A> to List<B> with Dozer?

Tags: list, dictionary, dozer

I have a service which returns a `List` of, say, `A` objects.
I want to transform it to a `List` of, say, `B` objects.

I have defined a mapping from `A` to `B`.

Naively, I tried to do

```
List<A> ayes = ... // call to service
List<B> bees = dozerMapper.map(ayes, new ArrayList<B>().getClass());
```

However, `bees` is still a `List` of `A` objects.

What should I be doing?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can achieve this in Dozer using hints http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/collectionandarraymapping.html, but we found creating a wrapper around the default Mapper easier.  An example is below.  You can then just rely on the default customer converters/mappers you have defined to do the mapping.

```
CollectionMapperDecorator custom = new CollectionMapperDecorator(dozerMapper);
Collection<B> bees = custom.mapCollection(ayes, B.class);

public class CollectionMapperDecorator implements Mapper
{
   private Mapper baseMapper;

   public CollectionMapperDecorator(Mapper baseMapper)
   {
      this.baseMapper = baseMapper;      
   }

   public <T> Collection<T> mapCollection(Object[] source, Class<T> destinationClass)
   {
      return mapCollection(Arrays.asList(source), destinationClass);
   }

   public <T> Collection<T> mapCollection(Object[] source, Collection<T> destination, Class<T> destinationClass)
   {
      return mapCollection(Arrays.asList(source), destination, destinationClass);
   }

   public <T> Collection<T> mapCollection(Collection<? extends Object> source, Class<T> destinationClass)
   {      
      return mapCollection(source, null, destinationClass);
   }   

   public <T> Collection<T> mapCollection(Collection<? extends Object> source, Collection<T> destination, Class<T> destinationClass)
   {
      if(destination == null)
         destination = new ArrayList<T>();

      for(Object sourceObj : source)
      {
         destination.add(map(sourceObj, destinationClass));
      }

      return destination;      
   }

   public <T> T map(Object source, Class<T> destinationClass, String mapId) throws MappingException
   {
      return baseMapper.map(source, destinationClass, mapId);
   }

   public <T> T map(Object source, Class<T> destinationClass) throws MappingException
   {
      return baseMapper.map(source, destinationClass);
   }

   public void map(Object source, Object destination, String mapId) throws MappingException
   {
      baseMapper.map(source, destination, mapId);
   }

   public void map(Object source, Object destination) throws MappingException
   {
      baseMapper.map(source, destination);
   }
}
```